# Dynamic camera zoom in google maps for different screen size

Tags: android, google-maps, zooming

I have goole maps included in my android app. The map markers has to come from the database and it has to move to the marker location in a way that the map displays all the markers on the screen.
Currently I am able to achieve this but I am a bit confused about the zoom level value. It does not seem to work correctly on all the device sizes.

I would want the map to zoom dynamically based on the screen size. This is my code below:

```
    LatLngBounds.Builder latLngBounds = new LatLngBounds.Builder(); ;

    foreach (var item in propertyList)
    {
        LatLng markerPosition = new LatLng(Convert.ToDouble(item.Latitude), Convert.ToDouble(item.Longitude));
        var point = GoogleMap.AddMarker(GetMarker(item, markerPosition));
        point.Tag = point.Position;
        point.Draggable = true;
        MobMarkers.Add(point);
        latLngBounds.Include(markerPosition);
    }
 GoogleMap.AnimateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.NewLatLngBounds(latLngBounds.Build(), 150));
```

I assume that it is not zooming the map properly is because of the fixed `150` value I gave in my code.

Can anyone please help me out with the value I need to put? Thanks in advance.